# TermDocumentMatrix not working on corpus

Tags: r, term-document-matrix

Trying to load many email files and let R learn what's spam or ham. First, I created a corpus, I want to create a term document, I received an error. How to fix it?

```
email_corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(NA))

setwd("C:/ham_spam/")

library(tm)
library(stringr)

email_corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(NA))

folders <- c("easy_ham/", "spam_2/")

for(n in 1:2){
  folder <- folders[n]
  for(i in 1:length(list.files(folder))){
    email <- list.files(folder)[i]
    tmp <- readLines(str_c(folder, email))
    tmp <- str_c(tmp, collapse = "")
    tmp_corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(tmp))
    email_corpus <- c(email_corpus, tmp_corpus)
  }
}

dtm_email <- DocumentTermMatrix(email_corpus)
```

Here is the error i received

> Error in UseMethod("TermDocumentMatrix", x) : 
>         no applicable method for 'TermDocumentMatrix' applied to an object of class "list"

below is an example of email_corpus, email_corpus is a list of data frames.

```
$meta
$language
[1] "en"

attr(,"class")
[1] "CorpusMeta"

$dmeta
data frame with 0 columns and 1 row

$content
[1] "From Steve_Burt@cursor-system.com  Thu Aug 22 12:46:39 2002Return-Path: <Steve_Burt@cursor-system.com>Delivered-To: zzzz@localhost.netnoteinc.comReceived: from localhost (localhost [127.0.0.1])\tby phobos.labs.netnoteinc.com (Postfix) with ESMTP id BE12E43C34\tfor... <truncated>
```

Answer (score 0):

Combining two corpora with `c()` removes the `Corpus` type by transforming it into a simple `list`.

On the other hand, using `VCorpus` and `c()` will preserve the `VCorpus` type.

Replace all your `Corpus` functions by `VCorpus` and the problem should be solved.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach:

Set the working directory to the folder that contains both your ham and spam folders:

```
setwd('/path/to/dir/that/contains/folders/')

folders <- c("easy_ham/", "spam_2/")
```

You can then list all (in this case `'.txt'`) files in you working directory (default `path` in `list.files()` is `'.'`)

```
emails <- list.files(pattern = ".txt", # assuming all emails are .txt files
                     recursive = TRUE) # recurse listing in subdirs

library(stringr)
library(tm)
```

You can then use `lapply()` to read the files:

```
email_txt <- lapply(emails, function(x) {
  tmp <- readLines(x)
  tmp <- str_c(tmp, collapse = "")
  return(tmp)
})
```

Create a corpus from the read text:

```
email_corpus <- VCorpus(VectorSource(email_txt))
```

And finally create a `DocumentTermMatrix` from that corpus:

```
dtm_email <- DocumentTermMatrix(email_corpus)
```